# Frequently occuring error "SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server."

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

Unfortunately, the ODBC driver for MSSQL does not always work with my PHP queries. I often get the error message:

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Go to the following URL to download the ODBC driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=1637121

But when I refresh the page it may work again (or it may not work again and I have to refresh again).

When I search for the error message, I only find results that the driver should be installed. However, the driver is installed and is also displayed in the phpinfo().

phpinfo odbc:

[image: phpinfo odbc]

phpinfo PDO:

[image: phpinfo pdo]

It doesn't matter if the PDO connection is established via odbc or sqlsrv, the error message won't disappear permanently. It appears on a server with PHP 7 as well as on one with PHP 8.

**Addition**: The error occurs during the connection process. So I tried to put it inside a loop, so if the first connection try fails, a second or third might succeed. But even 100 tries fail. Either the first try succeed or it doesn't work at all.

```php
while ($count < $maxTries) {
    try {
        $conn = null;
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=" . $host . " ; Database = " . $db . "", $user, $pw);
        
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $count = $maxTries;
        echo "Connection SUCCESSFUL";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $count2 = 0;
        while($count2 < $maxTries2) {
            try {
                $conn2 = null;
                $conn2 = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=" . $host . " ; Database = " . $db . "", $user, $pw);
                
                $conn2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $count2 = $maxTries2;
                echo "Connection2 SUCCESSFUL";
            } catch (Exception $e1) {
                $count2++;
                echo "$count2 . Connecting to $host: <br>";
                echo "$count2 Connection failed ... <br>";
                #die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
            } 
        }
        $count++;
        echo "$count . Connecting to $host: <br>";
        time_nanosleep(0, 250);
        // handle exception
        if ($count == $maxTries) {
            echo "$count Connection failed ... <br>";
            die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards, the $conn variable is still null and queries fail to execute.

Do you have any ideas on how I can solve this problem permanently?

Comment: I don't think that's the ODBC driver that the message is referring to. PHP has no way to know whether it's installed or not (at least on Windows, I don't know how it works on Linux). Did you check this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Alvaro. I just checked the example connection scripts given in your mentioned website, and both of them a small output "Success Results: ..." with details of our MSSQL-Server. So I think the drivers should be installed correctly. 

But my PHP sites still showing me the error message I have written above --sometimes--. This is, what really confuses me.

Comment: You should improve [your previous question that was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75694601) instead of just creating another one that's more-or-less exactly the same content. This one is likely to get closed, too.

Comment: Is this a single Linux instance you're dealing with? The browser behavior makes it sound like multiple instances behind a load balancer and only some of the instances have the required drivers installed.

Comment: Yes, it is a single Linux instance with an Apache and PHP installed on it. The MSSQL Server is installed on a separate Windows Server.
The information given by the phpinfo() doesn't change and allways displays the ODBC and PDO drivers.

Comment: When do you get this message? On creating connection or issuing queries? It seems kinda strange it works randomly. Do you perhaps cache connections and they get stale or something?

Comment: I get this message on creating the connection. I've added some further details to my connection settings in the question post. On the SQL Server the max amount of simultanous connections is set to 0 and remote connections are allowed.

Comment: May I suggest you to check which version of ODBC is installed? Latest is v18. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem even after installing the latest version of the ODBC driver (Version 18 at the time of writting), running PHP 7.0 on Windows

I solved the issue uninstalling that version and installing Version 17 of the ODBC driver

[ODBC Driver download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35424428)